# Angular: Get child elements of a DIV

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

**HTML**

```
<div #container id="container">
  <a id="A"></a>
  <a id="B"></a>
  <a id="C"></a>
</div>
```

I want to fetch all the anchor tags in the div "container" and add click event to it from component.ts file. I tried with the following solutions in Angular but not sure whether this is the appropriate way. Kindly guide.

```
@ViewChild('container ') container : ElementRef;

this.container .nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(element => {
       console.log(element);
});
```

If you have a better solution then please guide.

Comment: Instead, you can set conditional event with flag. And all you need to do in run-time is to trigger flag which set enable event on the item.

Comment: is it going to be through a `ngFor`? if so you can create a `directive`

Comment: @Aravind - At present it's not ngFor but later on I may do it. So, in both ways I require a solution.

Comment: Does it have any practical purpose or is it curiosity?

Comment: @Aravind - I applied the below code & it works. Could you detail on how to use directive?ngOnInit() {
    this.ddLanguage.nativeElement.childNodes.forEach(element => {
      if (element.tagName === 'A') {
        element.onclick  = () => console.log(element.id);
      }
    });
  }

Comment: Why not add a (click) event in the template?

Comment: @Bibin is it just for your curiosity?

Comment: @Aravind: I was converting a jQuery script to angular, I hope you can understand now and am reluctant to post the project code. Thanks for your guidance on using the Directive for this scenario.